# Magento 2.4.2 Security Scan Falsely Reports Visbot Malware

Tags: security, magento2, malware

Visbot Malware is being reported from the Magento Security Scan tool on my Magento 2 store. This is malware that looks to have infected Magento 1 stores from 2016. For some reason it is being reported on my clean Magneto 2 server. The file referenced below does not exist. Has anyone else seen this?

One or more 'Visbot' malware checks failed.
media/tmp/design/file/default_luma_logo.jpg

Our hosting company Nexcess malware scanner did not pick anything up. Ecomscan didn't either. Neither did sitelock server scan.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with Magento 2.4.2-p1.
I asked Magento and they confirmed it is a false positive.
Here is their answer :

> Hi,
>
> I've been updated that this is a false positive. Currently, the HTTP
> 200 response with a non-empty response body to
>
> {/pub}/media/tmp/design/file/default_luma_logo.jpg will trigger the
> alert…
>
> The standard Magento behavior prior to 2.4.2 is to return HTTP 404
> response, the 2.4.2 returns the image placeholder. As far as we see,
> for any image request under ‘/media/tmp/’ this store returns an image
> placeholder if the file is not available. Please restrict the access
> to ‘{/pub}media/tmp/design/file/default_luma_logo.jpg’ at the
> webserver level.
>
> Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error during my weekly scan on March 28, 2021.

One or more 'Visbot' malware checks failed.
media/tmp/design/file/default_luma_logo.jpg

The file doesn't exist. I rescanned my site and the error no longer shows up. I'm thinking it's most likely a false positive / issue with Magento's scanning script.

By the way, I just moved off of Nexcess and onto Cloudways (Linode data center). Much more bang for your buck. Nexcess service and support (for Magento) is not as good since it merged with Liquid Web.

Comment: Thank you for confirming it as a false positive. I have contacted Magento Security Scan via email because one of our domains came back as:  fail Compromise BotNet Suspect There is a chance your domain takes part in BotNets activities. Please perform appropriate actions (on the right) and Email Us to remove your domain from potential `BotNet Participants` list.
Review your site for signs of compromise. Protect your Admin panel and other access points against password guessing and apply Security Best Practices.  I believe this is also a false positive w/Visbot and waiting to hear back.

Comment: How did you actually mail them? I  got the same problem but find no way of sending them a mail to remove my domain from the list of suspects.